# Is there a way to back up all the keybindings in Ubuntu (the ones in "Keyboard Shortcuts" UI)?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to back up and restore (from the command line) all the keybindings that are shown in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" UI? I'm not talking about just the custom ones that a user creates (which would be pretty easy), but the whole sh-bang.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101226/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-keyboard-shortcut-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Check out: `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings`

Comment: Close, but no cigar. :D  Commenting out the xml for a keybinding removes the keybinding from the list, but does NOT actually stop the keybinding from existing.  For example, I set the "Run Terminal" shortcut to ctrl-r, then comment out the xml for that keybinding.  While the keybinding for Run Terminal is no longer in the list when I run the gui, and the Run Terminal shortcut is no longer displayed, but I can still use ctrl-r to open a terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure we have the same understanding for the words "backup" and "restore". For me backing up means creating a tarball of the directory and sending it somewhere safe. For you it seems it means editing the files by hand and expecting it to work without actually forcing gnome itself instead of that applet to re-read the file. (P.S. CTRL-R already has a more useful usage in bash :( )

Comment: Backing up by copying the directory somewhere (by tarring or otherwise) is *exactly* what I'm trying to do.  I want to be able to do.  In particular, I want to do a fresh install of Ubuntu, bring in whatever I need, and blow away the fresh install keybindings with the set of keybindings that I have backed up.  And ctrl-r was arbitrary :P  :D